# Is it possible to implement Voice Interactions on Android 4.4?

Tags: android, google-search

Is it possible to implement Voice Interactions for Android 4.4?

If it possible so how to implement it?

https://io2015codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/voice-interaction#1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interact with your phone using `Speech to text` .while you speak.you can convert your speech to Text(String) and check it with a condition.the you can use `Text to speech` for getting audio output like `google now`.
refer this for [speech to text](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/) and [Text to Speech](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_text_to_speech.htm)

Answer (score 0):

We can see on Android reference that API added since API level 23 (M) [check here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/VoiceInteractor.html). So you can't use it in 4.4. 
The only way to to do Voice interactions with previews API version is to use TextToSpeech API, use SpeechRecognition service or implement SpeechListener interface (use SpeechRecognizer to do that) in order to do ASR.

I hope this help you.
See you ;).

Comment: Could you also provide some code sample? Links are not permanent, which makes them unreliable source.